# Changing font color with static columns and variable row range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling a bit in finding the proper syntax to change font colors of cells within a static column range (A:T) of cells, but variable rows.  All variables are properly defined, it is just the way I am writing this line of code that is causing me errors. Here is my current snippet:

```
 If Sheets("InfoSheet").Range("BR21").Value = True Then
     Sheets("AcctTable").Range(Cells(iOutputRow, "A"), Cells(iOutputRow, "T")).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
     Sheets("AcctTable").Range(Cells(iOutputRow, "A"), Cells(iOutputRow, "T")).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
 End If
```

I also tried the following code:

```
 If Sheets("InfoSheet").Range("BR21").Value = True Then
     Sheets("AcctTable").Range("A" & iOutputRow & ":" & "T" & iOutputRow).Font.Color = vbRed
 Else
     Sheets("AcctTable").Range("A" & iOutputRow & ":" & "T" & iOutputRow).Font.Color = vbBlack
 End If
```

But alas, I got errors in this as well.  Any insight?

**UPDATE:  My issue was with me not unprotecting the sheet before these lines of code.  I still updated my code with a variety of your comments though, so thank you all.**

Comment: Under `Options` have you selected `R1C1` way of addressing cells?

Comment: For a quick test, just do, say, `Sheets("AcctTable").Range("A10:T10").Font.Color = vbRed` and see if that works.  The first one probably needs `Sheets("AcctTable").` also added to the `Cells()`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry, didn't read the comments before I posted and it appears you had the same comment I answered with.  Very common problem and I'm just as guilty as most folks of it regularly!

Comment: @BruceWayne did the quick test and i still got an error.  The error is  'Run-Time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only glaring issue with the first set of code is inappropriate objects:

```
With Sheets("AcctTable")
    If Sheets("InfoSheet").Range("BR21").Value = True Then
        .Range( .Cells(iOutputRow, "A"), .Cells(iOutputRow, "T")).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        .Range( .Cells(iOutputRow, "A"), .Cells(iOutputRow, "T")).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I received the same error 'Application-defined or object-defined error'